Composing multi function imagemagick command for resize, adding background, changing greyscale, apply image-kernel, get pixel value mean
I want to resize, add a background, change to grayscale, apply an image-kernel for finding edges, and lastly get the mean value of pixels in the image.
What's wrong with my command?:
"imagic\magick.exe" "aaaa.png" -resize 800x800> ^ 
-background "#FFFFFF" -flatten -colorspace Gray ^
-morphologyConvolve "3x3: -1,-1,-1 -1,8,-1 -1,-1,-1" -format "%[fx:mean]" info:""


Please show your actual command - you are missing line continuation markers (^) at the ends of lines with continuation.

Also, as this is Windows, I think you have to maybe double up the percent sign, i.e. "%%[fx:mean]"

The simplest way to debug is generally to start with the first step of your pipeline and write the result to a file, i.e. up to -resize YxZ and check the file. Then add in -background ... -flatten and write to a new output file and check that. Then add -colorspace gray and write to a file and check it's what you expect and so on, till you find the culprit.

Any luck with my suggestions?

Hey there Mark. Thank you so much for your suggestions. Im currently on a vacation so i will try it on monday. The whole code is in one line, i just entered it into multiple for better readability on smaller screens.

How do you do line continuation?

On Linux, you put backslash at the end of each line to continue on the next. On Windows, you use caret ^. I presume you use Windows - because of magick.exe which nobody would use on Linux.

Yes i use windows. Why wouldnt u use magick.exe?

Linux/Unix and macOS are a bit more grown-up about filenames and names of programs.

Hi Mark Setchell. so the debugging method helped. i found the problem. also the double %% doesn't work, there should be only one.

size of resize and ">" needs to be in double quotes.
"imagic\magick.exe" "aaaa.png" -resize "800x800>" ^
-background "#FFFFFF" -flatten -colorspace Gray ^
-morphologyConvolve "3x3: -1,-1,-1 -1,8,-1 -1,-1,-1" -format "%[fx:mean]" info:""

